# Dynamically set item from <select> menu based on $state.params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I'm developing a feature where a user can repost a previously submitted 'project', which involves passing the data from the current project to $scope.params.project, archiving the existing project, and redirecting to the PostProject page where the user can resubmit the project, adjusting details in the form as needed.

The idea is that the PostProject form should be populated with the Job data from $scope.params so the user doesn't have to fill all of this out again.

I've successfully used this to populate a regular `<input>` field, so I know the data is being passed. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this with a `<select>` dropdown menu, however. Everything I find tells me to use ng-model to be able to set the `<select>` menu to a default value.

However, I need to set the menu to a value based on $scope.params and have that value set the model for when the form is submitted. I'm stumped.

Here's the HTML. Assuming that $state.params.project is the intended JS object and that $state.params.project.service_type is a string that exists in the postOppCtrl.services array, I think this is all that is needed to demonstrate the problem.

From the HTML:

```
<select ng-if="$state.params.project" 
        ng-model="postOppCtrl.postOppProjForm.service_type"
        ng-options="category as category for category in postOppCtrl.services"
        // this part doesn't work, and I'm not sure what else to try.
        ng-value="$state.params.project.service_type"
        </select>
```

Comment: Can you post the values of `postOppCtrl.postOppProjForm.service_type`, `postOppCtrl.services`, and `$state.params.project.service_type`? If I have that I can create a JSFiddle for you with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ng-init in the select tag to initialize the value:

`ng-init="postOppCtrl.postOppProjForm.service_type = $state.params.project.service_type`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My coworker helped me come up with a solution which I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the model from my controller using $scope.

In my PostOpportunityController I had:

```
vm.postOppProjForm = {};
```

I replaced that with:

```
 vm.postOppProjForm = { service_type: $state.params.project.service_type };
```